# Loading UIImage from disk sometimes fails with permission error in background state?

Tags: ios, iphone, file-io, background-process

I have this strange issue that I am having trouble resolving. I am creating an App which allows music to be played back. When the screen is locked (and there is a currently playing song), the lock screen will populate with a bunch of data. One piece is the album art.

The problem is that after the phone is locked and I skip a few tracks (forwards or backwards), the UIImages are no longer being loaded. If I test out the functionality and quickly skip forward and backwards in my playback queue, the album art will appear for the first 4-5 songs. After that, the images stop appearing because I get a NSFileReadNoPermissionError from my code that grabs the image. I understand that I apparently do not have permission to access the png image files, but I do not understand why. My application created them, saved them on disk, and is now trying to load them from disk while my app is running in a background state.

The relevant code snippet:

```
+ (void)updateLockScreenInfoAndArtForSong:(Song *)song
{

    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *artDirPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Album Art"];
    NSString *path = artDirPath;
    //-----> LIST ALL FILES for debugging <-----//
    NSLog(@"LISTING ALL FILES FOUND");

    int count;
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path
                                                                                    error:NULL];
    for (count = 0; count < (int)[directoryContent count]; count++)
    {
        NSLog(@"File %d: %@", (count + 1), [directoryContent objectAtIndex:count]);
    }
    //-----> END DEBUG CODE <-----//


    Song *nowPlayingSong = [MusicPlaybackController nowPlayingSong];

    Class playingInfoCenter = NSClassFromString(@"MPNowPlayingInfoCenter");
    if (playingInfoCenter) {
        NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        NSError *error;
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [AlbumArtUtilities albumArtFileNameToNSURL:nowPlayingSong.albumArtFileName] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
        NSInteger code = error.code;
        NSLog(@"Error code: %li", (long)code);    //prints 257 sometimes, which is NSFileReadNoPermissionError

        UIImage *albumArtImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        if(albumArtImage == nil){  //song has no album art, check if its album does
            Album *songsAlbum = song.album;
            if(songsAlbum){
                albumArtImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                                        [AlbumArtUtilities albumArtFileNameToNSURL:songsAlbum.albumArtFileName]]];
            }
        }

        [songInfo setObject:nowPlayingSong.songName forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        NSInteger duration = [nowPlayingSong.duration integerValue];
        [songInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:duration]
                     forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
        [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];
    }
}
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated! I have tried so many thing that I am at a loss for what to even try next. Note the above code snippet is called in

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

when event.subtype is UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack or UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after trying everything all day lol. Turns out that by default in iOS 8, much of the system is encrypted (files cannot be accessed after the phone is locked)...with a small delay of course. This is why a few album art images were loading but they stopped working after a few seconds. The delay between when the phone locked and the encryption enabled itself made it seem like my issue was "random".

Anyway for anyone reading this, my solution involved setting the file protection of all folders and subfolder and files leading to the album art directory.

Hint:

```
[attributes setValue:NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication forKey:NSFileProtectionKey];
```

Set that attribute on a file when it is being created (provide the information as an NSDictionary). If an existing directory or file is to be modified, gather the attributes of the thing using NSFileManager, and then set the values as shown above.